# Uploading a server certificate error: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: certificate, putty

I can't figure out how to get pass this error:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here is how I have my code set up:

```
aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name *.giving.school.com --certificate-body file://givingschooleducert.pem --private-key file://private-key.pem --certificate-chain file://givingschooleduinterm.pem
```

What can I do to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was two things that was causing this error. One was that I was using incorrect chain file and the reverse intermediate.pem was the correct certificate to use and second, when I converted the CER file into a PEM I used putty to convert it and the PEM files were encrypted...

The best way to convert a CER into a PEM is to just rename it on a text editor haha.